# How to retrieve all the data from a node in Android Firebase realtime database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase data:

[image]

I wanted to retrieve all the data from child("Registo Inicial e Final") and display in a table or in a list view.

My code from android studio :

```
reff2 = database.getInstance().getReference().child("Registo Inicial e Final");

            reff2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Log.e("MATRICULAAAAAAAAAAAAA", String.valueOf(ds.child("matricula").getValue()));


                        try {


                            if (ds.child("matricula").getValue().equals(editText_Matric.getText().toString())) {

                                String message = ds.child("nome_CONDUTOR").getValue().toString();
                                String message2 = ds.child("matricula").getValue().toString();
                                String message3 = ds.child("cod_PROJETO").getValue().toString();
                                String message4 = ds.child("km_INICIAL").getValue().toString();
                                String message5 = ds.child("km_FINAL").getValue().toString();
                                String message6 = ds.child("data_INICIO").getValue().toString();
                                String message7 = ds.child("data_FIM").getValue().toString();
                                String message8 = ds.child("hora_INICIO").getValue().toString();
                                String message9 = ds.child("hora_FIM").getValue().toString();
                                String message10 = ds.child("observacoes").getValue().toString();

                                Nome.setText(message);
                                Matricula.setText(message2);
                                Cod.setText(message3);
                                Kilometros_inicial.setText(message4);
                                Kilometros_final.setText(message5);
                                Data_inicial.setText(message6);
                                Data_final.setText(message7);
                                Hora_inicial.setText(message8);
                                Hora_final.setText(message9);
                                Observacoes.setText(message10);
```

Output:

It´s only showing the data from only one record (only from one firebase push key), but I want all the data from all push keys..

[image]

Comment: What is happening when you are using the shared code?

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading all the data because you specified an `if-statement` to get only those for the corresponding `matricula` string that is typed in the `EditText`:

**Remove this `if-statement`**

```
if (ds.child("matricula").getValue().equals(editText_Matric.getText().toString())) {

......
.....
```

And you will get all the values then maybe store them in a `list`

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is you're getting the whole snapshot with all the children, then your statement `if (ds.child("matricula").getValue().equals(editText_Matric.getText().toString()))` is filtering out all the other children, except where `matricula` is equal to the txt in `editText_Matric`. In your screenshot, it shows that your editText_Matric text value was "90-29-VE", so you only got that one result for Miguel Carvalho.

Comment: I removed the if, and on the log it shows all the values, but then in the text field on the app it shows only one value :/

Comment: You need to use something like a ListView. Otherwise, looks like every time it is going to the next record, it is overwriting the previous one.

Comment: There is no way to fill the table with the various records of the firebase ??

Comment: You can either make the UI as a listview: as you loop through your data records, store in an ArrayList, then make an adapter use that ArrayList to provide the rows for your table; OR you can change your layout to put in row by row, so you'll have separate textviews, etc. for each row, then write your data to the separate textviews instead of over-writing the same views again and again.